# 日本語に違和感: 「モデレーターとは?」の説明文

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

> モデレーターとは?
>
> 弊社では、モデレーションはコミュニティ自体から始まるべきものであると考えます。したがって弊社では、信用度によって獲得した特権に加えて、民主的なモデレーター選挙を定期的に開催します。
>
> 弊社のモデレーション哲学に関する情報については、モデレーションの理論をご覧ください。

- 「モデレーション」という単語はあまり一般的でない気がする
- 「コミュニティ自体から始まる」「モデレーション哲学」に違和感
- モデレーターとは何なのか、結局よくわからない

英語版:

> Who are the moderators?
>
> We believe moderation starts with the community itself, so in addition to privileges earned through reputation, we periodically hold democratic moderator elections.
>
> Please see A Theory of Moderation for information on our moderation philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

> モデレーター一覧
>
> Stack Exchange では、各 Q&A コミュニティがそれぞれ最大限自律的に自治・自己管理できる仕組みを整えようとしています。その範囲はコミュニティ自体の管理にも及びます。そのため、信用度の蓄積を通してさまざまな管理権限を得られる仕組みに加え、定期的に民主的投票でユーザーの中からモデレーターを選ぶという仕組みを取り入れています。
>
> Stack Exchange が考えるモデレーションのあり方については、A Theory of Moderationに詳しく書かれています。

- A Theory of Moderationに書かれている内容を冒頭の一文に反映しました

Comment: 念のため確認です。「Stack Exchange」でOKでしょうか。ここでは「Stack Overflow」かなと思ったので。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @naota うーん、どういう立場から"we"と言っているかといえば、Q&AコミュニティのプラットフォームであるStack Exchangeではないかとは思います。が、他に日本語の兄弟サイトがない今はStack Overflowの方がわかりやすいかもしれないですね